# Sending email from Magento to fails

Tags: zend-framework, email, magento

I am trying to send an email from a custom module in magento, however it fails to send it.
do i need to include anything or should i make some configuration with my hosting?
Here you can see my code:

```
                $mail = new Zend_Mail();  
                $mail->setBodyText($mailbody);
                $mail->setFrom('admin@gmail.com', 'admin');
                $mail->addTo('email@gmail.com', 'client');
                $mail->setSubject('Error report');


                try {
                    $mail->send();
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
                    }
```

Comment: How does it fail? What happens?

Comment: It does not send the email and the "Unable to send" shown on page

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Magento's models for sending email. This way you know it's being send correctly, and get userful errors when it fails

The most simply way:

```
$email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$email->setSenderEmail('sender@email.com');
$email->setSenderName('name');
$email->setTemplateSubject('Subject');
$email->setTemplateText('emailbody');
$email->send('receiver@mail.com', 'receiver name');
```

Remember that you host my not support sending mail, or that your provider is blocking port 25. This will result in a message in your exception.log

If you want to see how the final email looks, print `$email->getProcessedTemplate()` onto your screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your smtp in `php.ini`
What is your provider ? It's possible to find the smtp server's url, and put it in your `php.ini` file.